# Summing 2nd list items in a list of lists of lists

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

My data is a list of lists of lists of varying size:

```
data = [[[1, 3],[2, 5],[3, 7]],[[1,11],[2,15]],.....]]]
```

What I want to do is return a list of lists with the values of the 2nd element of each list of lists summed - so, 3+5+7 is a list, so is 11+15, etc:

```
newdata = [[15],[26],...]
```

Or even just a list of the sums would be fine as I can take it from there:

```
newdata2 = [15,26,...]
```

I've tried accessing the items in the list through different forms and structures of list comprehensions, but I can't get seem to get it to the format I want.

Comment: Can you show us the code you've written so far while solving the problem ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this one-line approach using list comprehension:

```
[sum([x[1] for x in i]) for i in data]
```

Output:

```
data = [[[1, 3],[2, 5],[3, 7]],[[1,11],[2,15]]]
[sum([x[1] for x in i]) for i in data]
Out[19]: [15, 26]
```

If you want the output to be a list of list, then use

```
[[sum([x[1] for x in i])] for i in data]
```

Comment: I think the OP want it just one level deeper, so `[[sum([x[1] for x in i])] for i in data]`. Nevertheless +1...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, thanks for the helpful comment and edited the answer.

Answer (score 4):

@mathmax and @BrendanAbel have offered Pythonic and performant solutions. However, I want to throw this transpositional approach into the ring for the sake of its brevity and trickyness:

```
[sum(zip(*x)[1]) for x in data]
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this is pretty short and concise, using list comprehensions and `map` (I try not to use nested comprehensions if I can avoid it)

```
import operator

f = operator.itemgetter(1)
[sum(map(f, x)) for x in data]
```